# How can I compare two 2D arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

İ try it, but this code not run stable.

İ have two 2D arrays `first[a][b]` and `second[x][y]`.

I want to compare these two arrays. How can I do this?

My code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            if (first[i][j] == second[i][j])
                return 1;
```

Comment: You should  `return` when they  are **not** equal so use `!=`.

Comment: As Weather Vane points out, the loop needs to look for *unequal* elements.  As soon as it finds an unequal pair, it can return 0.  If it exits both loops, then all elements were equal, and it can return 1.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way would be using `memcmp`.

**NOTE:** This will work on modern architectures, where `int` does not have any padding bits. Thanks for @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes to pointing this out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int a[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
  int b[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
  int c[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 123}};
  int ret;

  ret = memcmp(a, b, 3 * 3 * sizeof(int));

  if (ret == 0)
    printf("a equal b\n");
  else
    printf("a not equal b\n");

  ret = memcmp(a, c, 3 * 3 * sizeof(int));

  if (ret == 0)
    printf("a equal c\n");
  else
    printf("a not equal c\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
a equal b
a not equal c
```

Comment: Haha nice to meet you again, I didn't know what `memcmp` was until this point. Upvoted ;)

Comment: @ArdentCoder The more you know ;)

Comment: `memcmp(a, b, 3 * 3 * sizeof(int));` could be simplified as `memcmp(a, b, sizeof a);`.  Note however that this method is inappropriate if type `int` has padding bits, so you might add a caveat such as *On modern architectures where `int` does not have any padding bits, ...*

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Will do. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Through your code, I see that:

> both the arrays are equal if one of the corresponding elements in the arrays are
>   equal.

But I think you want this:

> both the arrays are equal if all the corresponding elements in the arrays are equal

That does not happen in your code because you are `return`ing immediately when one of the corresponding elements are equal (`==`), so the remaining checks are omitted by your code.

**Solution:**

Change `if( first[i][j]==second[i][j])` to `if (first[i][j] != second[i][j])`

This will look for the first unequal element. Then you can `return` the appropriate message or perhaps `break` depending on what exactly you are doing with that code.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but the arrays are identical if all entries are. You should return 0 when you find a difference and return 1 otherwise:

```c
int compare_matrices(int first[10][10], int second[10][10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (first[i][j] != second[i][j])
                return 0;
       }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

An alternative for regular architectures without padding bits would use `memcmp()`:

```c
#include <string.h>

int compare_matrices(int first[10][10], int second[10][10]) {
    return !memcmp(first, second, 10 * sizeof(*first));
}
```

The first code is simplistic but the compiler can optimize it by unrolling the loops and may produce performance comparable or better than that of `memcmp()`.

Reducing the number of tests would increase the number of memory accesses but may produce better performance as the compiler can use SIMD instructions:

```
int compare_matrices(int first[10][10], int second[10][10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            res |= (first[i][j] != second[i][j]);
        }
        if (res) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

You can use [GodBolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rL8Y9-) to compare code generators.